# Created an auto-like Twitter bot with Tweepy but get an error

Tags: python, tweepy

Hope you're fine.

I've followed a tutorial on how to create an auto-like Twitter bot using Tweepy. After many errors I've seen that Tweepy has changed some terms.

After making some changes like on `except tweepy.TweepError` to `except tweepy.errors.TweepError`. The code doesn't run properly. Was searching everywhere and could not find a solution to my problem.

I've also set on Twitter settings App to Read and Write.

Here is the code. It is pretty straightforward:

```
import time

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("CONSUMER_KEY","CONSUMER_SECRET")
auth.set_access_token("ACCESS_TOKEN","TOKEN_SECRET")

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)


search = "#crypto OR #nft"
nrTweets = 500

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets, search).items(nrTweets):
    try:
        print("Tweet Liked")
        tweet.favorite()
        time.sleep(60)
    except tweepy.errors.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

And here the error message. It just not that is not executing the program. It is also the except error is wrong. And I'm following the suggestions that I've seen on tutorial.

```
Tweet Liked
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zaesar/Escritorio/coding/python-twitter-bot/twitter.py", line 16, in <module>
    tweet.favorite()
  File "/home/zaesar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/models.py", line 371, in favorite
    return self._api.create_favorite(self.id)
  File "/home/zaesar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zaesar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 925, in create_favorite
    return self.request(
  File "/home/zaesar/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tweepy/api.py", line 257, in request
    raise Unauthorized(resp)
tweepy.errors.Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
Read-only application cannot POST.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zaesar/Escritorio/coding/python-twitter-bot/twitter.py", line 18, in <module>
    except tweepy.errors.TweepError as e:
AttributeError: module 'tweepy.errors' has no attribute 'TweepError'
```

Any help will be really appreciated as I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

I made everything fine but after setting to Read and Write on the Twitter App. You need to regenerate the Keys and Tokens. Hope this helps to other people!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).